# Brzozowki's algorithm doesn't work for this corner case

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

I'm a newbee learning DFA minimization. And I found that(strangely) Brzozowki's algorithm cannot give me a minimized DFA on this example:
[image]
In this DFA, $S_0$ and $S_1$ are nondistinguishable and should be merged after minimization, but they are not.
The process of minimization is like this:
[image]
I tried to find out why by reading @Hendrik Jan's proof here, [Proof of Brzozowski's algorithm for DFA minimization?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/105574/proof-of-brzozowskis-algorithm-for-dfa-minimization)

However, I find that this case bypasses the proof, because that in the reversed DFA, the initial state $q_0$ cannot be reached by $q_0$ using any words (but initial state is always considered reachable and cannot be removed). So did I miss anything, or does Brzozowki's algorithm has any specification for this corner case?

(It bypasses the proof like this: in the second series of reversal-determinization, $S_0 = \{q_1\}$ and $S_1 = \{q_0, q_1\}$, for any $w$, $\delta(q_0, w)$ in $S_0$ iff $\delta(q_0, w)$ in $S1$, so we say $S_0 
= S_1$, assuming all states can be reached by $\delta(q_0, w)$, but $\delta(q_0,w)$ will never be $q_0$)

the initial DFA I was working on:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have looked into some other corner cases and have a tentative answer: when we are doing the determinization after reversal, there is a corner case where in the DFA before reversal, some states cannot be reached  by applying any word to the initial state (two possibilities: the initial state cannot go back to itself or we are adding a state as the new initial state, because when we are doing reversal, there are 2 or more final states). In these cases, two sets are considered the same set if the only differences between them are the "unreachable" states before reversal.

---

**Correction**:

Rici made things clearer as he commented "$S_0$  is not a final state and $S_1$ is. So they cannot be merged", since "the merged DFA accepts $\epsilon$. The original one does not. So they are not equivalent".

I finally find out my issue. Actually the example I gave above is my "DIY" version trying to make it simpler. And the initial one that I didn't get right is updated in the question. I found out that I used the approach mentioned in Udacity course to do the minimization using Brzozowki's algorithm, which is creating a new state as initial state in the reversed NFA, when there are 2 or more final states. And if two sets are different only on the "created" initial states, I treated them as two different ones, which is not true. I shouldn't add a new state at the beginning.

I think we can prove that by reversing the proof process in the link cited in the question.